# Scope of list changes done in a function to called function

Tags: python, list, scope

I have two functions `foo()` and `bar()`, which use two lists `l1` and `l2`.

`foo()` makes a function call to `bar()` with `l1` and `l2` as arguments.

`bar()` mutates the lists `l1` and `l2`. `foo()` needs to know of these changes to the lists hence the lists are returned by `bar()`.

Instead of this passing of lists as arguments and returning them is there a better way to update the lists in `foo()`?

```
def bar(l1, l2):
     value=10
     l1.append(value)
     l2.append(value)
     return l1,l2

def foo() :
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    list1, list2 = bar(list1,list2)

def main():
    foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Right now, `func1` doesn't call `func2`. So it will not be aware of anything `func2` does. `func2` modifies the lists in place. So if you /were/ to call `func2` from inside `func1`, `func1` would be aware of the changes that `func2` made to `list1` and `list2`

Comment: i dont think this code will run...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: you're right. This code is not legal. Will raise `NameError` when calling `func2`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - I just created a sample code,please dont look over the syntax details...

Comment: Both functions are independent. That doesn't look intended.

Comment: Looks like you were intending to use global variables?

Comment: @BorrajaX - anyother way other than using global,prefer not to use global

Comment: @user1927233: You are modifying **IN-PLACE**. This means that you don't need to use global vars. Read my first comment

Comment: @all - I modified the code..it should run now

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - can you please look at the code now?I made it runnable

Comment: @user1927233: read the second sentence in my first comment. It is still applicable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned since you are modifying the contents - **in-place** - of the lists passed in you do not need to return anything

```
def func2 (list1,list2):
     value=10
     list1.append(value)
     list2.append(value)

listA = [1,2,3]
listB = [7,8,9]

func2(listA,listB)

print listA
print listB
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description and your comments, it sounds like your real `func2` looks like this:

```
def func2(list1, list2):
    value = 'a'
    list1.append(value)
    list2.append(value)
    return list1,list2
```

This mutates `list1` and `list2` in place, so whoever calls it is going to see the changes. And it *also* returns `list` and `list2`, so whoever calls it can use the results that way.

So, in func1:

```
def func1() :
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    func2(list1, list2)
    print(list1, list2)
```

You're going to see that both values are `['a']`.

And if you do this:

```
(list1,list2) = func2([],[])
print(list1, list2)
```

You're *also* going to see that both values are `['a']`.

You don't actually need—or usually want—to both mutate the values *and* return them. Just do one or the other:

```
def mutating_func2(list1, list2):
    value = 'a'
    list1.append(value)
    list2.append(value)

def non_mutating_func2(list1, list2):
    value = 'a'
    return list1+[value], list2+[value]
```

You can use `mutating_func2` in code like `func1`, which just passes two lists and expects to have them modified. You can use `non_mutating_func2` in code like your top-level code, which passes two lists and expects to get back two new lists. Both are perfectly reasonable things to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your modified question, there is no need to return the lists, they are passed by reference anyway and will be modified:

```
def func2 (list1,list2):
     value=10
     list1.append(value)
     list2.append(value)

def func1() :
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    func2(list1,list2)
    print "list1:",list1,"list2:",list2
    func2(list1,list2)
    print "list1:",list1,"list2:",list2
    func2(list1,list2)
    print "list1:",list1,"list2:",list2

def main():
    func1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Gives:

```
list1: [10] list2: [10]
list1: [10, 10] list2: [10, 10]
list1: [10, 10, 10] list2: [10, 10, 10]
```

Answer (score -1):

I have modified your code as follows:

```
def func2(list1, list2):
     value=10
     list1.append(value)
     list2.append(value)

def func1():
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    func2(list1,list2)
```

Notice that `func2` does not return anything. This is not a problem, since it uses `list.append`, which modifies the list **IN-PLACE**. This means that when `func2` finishes execution, the changes to `list1` and `list2` still persist.

On the other hand, if you were to have done `list1 = list1 + [5]`, that is a change that would not persist after `func2` finished execution.

Thus, with the above code, `func1` will be aware of changes made to the two lists by `func2` even after the execution of `func2` is complete.

```
In [13]: def func2(list1, list2):
   ....:     value = 'a'
   ....:     list1.append(value)
   ....:     list2.append(value)
   ....:     

In [14]: def func1():
   ....:     myList = []
   ....:     myOtherList = [1]
   ....:     print myList, myOtherList
   ....:     func2(myList, myOtherList)
   ....:     print myList, myOtherList
   ....:     

In [15]: func1()
[] [1]
['a'] [1, 'a']


In [16]: def otherfunc2(list1, list2):
   ....:     value = 'a'
   ....:     list1 = list1 + [value]
   ....:     list2 = list2 + [value]
   ....:     


In [17]: def func1():
   ....:     myList = []
   ....:     myOtherList = [1]
   ....:     print myList, myOtherList
   ....:     otherfunc2(myList, myOtherList)
   ....:     print myList, myOtherList
   ....:     

In [18]: func1()
[] [1]
[] [1]
```

Comment: `list1 += [5]` _does_ persist after `func` finishes execution. That's a mutating operation, just like `append`. At least it is for `list`, other standard mutating collections, and any custom class that defines a mutating `__iadd__`.

Comment: @abarnert: you're right. I've edited to clarify what I meant. Thanks for catching that typo